# How to automatically add Dropwizard Metrics @Timed into all APIs method in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dropwizard, codahale-metrics

I have an Spring Boot application integrated with Dropwizard Metrics following this [link](https://ivanursul.com/monitoring-your-spring-application-using-dropwizard-metrics-module).

When I added the `@Timed` annotation into some APIs (controller methods) it showed on the metrics link.

For example, for below `RestController`:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @GET
    @Path("/ping")
    @Timed
    @ApiOperation("Ping server")    
    public Response Ping() {
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

then result is as follows:

```
"timers": {
    "com.test.testcontroller.Ping": {
        "count": 0,
        "max": 0.0,
        "mean": 0.0,
        "min": 0.0,
        "p50": 0.0,
        "p75": 0.0,
        "p95": 0.0,
        "p98": 0.0,
        "p99": 0.0,
        "p999": 0.0,
        "stddev": 0.0,
        "m15_rate": 0.0,
        "m1_rate": 0.0,
        "m5_rate": 0.0,
        "mean_rate": 0.0,
        "duration_units": "seconds",
        "rate_units": "calls/second"
    }
}
```

I have around 20 controllers with a total of 130 APIs (methods) so I would like to configure a wide annotation or inject the `@Timed` annotation automatically. Something like:

```
@RestController
@Timed
public class TestController {
    @GET
    @Path("/ping")
    @ApiOperation("Ping server")    
    // timed will auto applied in here
    public Response Ping() {
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: How have you activated the *Dropwizard Metrics*? Could you add the configuration part?

Answer (score 0):

`@Timed` metric instrumentation [is not supported at `Class` (`Controller`) level](https://github.com/ryantenney/metrics-spring/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ryantenney/metrics/spring/TimedMethodInterceptor.java#L37). Here donw an excerpt of the adviced *pointcut* (from the *metrics-spring* integration library):

```java
class TimedMethodInterceptor extends AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor<Timed, Timer> implements Ordered {

    public static final Class<Timed> ANNOTATION = Timed.class;
    public static final Pointcut POINTCUT = new AnnotationMatchingPointcut(null, ANNOTATION);
    public static final MethodFilter METHOD_FILTER = new AnnotationFilter(ANNOTATION, PROXYABLE_METHODS);

    public TimedMethodInterceptor(final MetricRegistry metricRegistry, final Class<?> targetClass) {
        super(metricRegistry, targetClass, ANNOTATION, METHOD_FILTER);
    }
//...
}
```

As you can see from above excerpt, `@Timed` annotations are only matched at `method` level.

You will then have to either adapt the library sources and use a custom build for it ([take good note of the library licence](https://github.com/ryantenney/metrics-spring/blob/master/LICENSE)) or add the timer metric annotation explicitly over all you API methods.